# Error on librados when trying to install qemu-kvm

Tags: kubuntu, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am trying to install kvm on Kubuntu 16.04 64-bit. I am following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) documentation. When I try to install qemu-kvm with the following command given in the documentation:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

I have the following errors:

```
http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ceph/librados2_10.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ceph/librbd1_10.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

Did I do something wrong (I just followed the documentation)? Is the documentation obsolete? Is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You may need to `sudo apt update` first. If that doesn't help, there is an error in the package itself. However, you can easily download the correct version of these dependencies. Look [here](http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ceph/) and download what you need. Then install these packages with `sudo dpkg -i name-of-package.deb`. Then try your `apt-get` statement again.

Comment: As @Jos suggested after typing 'sudo apt upgrade' I was able to install qemu-kvm. Thank you @Jos!!